# Turning Oracle Materialized View to Table and back again

Tags: oracle, scheduler, materialized-views, oracle19c

We have a materialized view (MV) on Oracle 19c. Its data is updated/refreshed by scheduler job every day.

Because of some maintenance work that may last for more than 6 months, I would like to update some data inside it manually. However, manual update is forbidden on MV.

It may sound stupid but I am planning to:

1. Disable to the scheduler job
2. Turn the MV into table (DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW .. PRESERVE TABLE; )

Then we can update the table data manually for our maintenance work.

After the maintenance work, I would:

1. Turn the table back to MV
2. Re-enable the scheduler job to refresh the data

So the question is... how do I turn the table back to MV *SAFELY* in my case? It is easy to turn MV into table but I have never heard anyone doing it the other way round.

By *safely*, I mean that the reverted MV is back to before without lost of behaviours/properties.

If I turn the MV to table and then back to MV, would the index still work for both the table and the MV without affected?
Similarly, if we already have a synonym for the MV, would this synonym still work after converting to table and back to MV again?
Do I need re-grant any user privileges to the table and later for the MV again?

Note: I am aware that after turning the table back to MV, the data get refreshed and our manual data would be lost. That is acceptable for us because we just want the manual data to stay during the maintenance period.

If there are other suggestions/alternatives, I am happy to hear.

Comment: What do you mean "safely"? Creating an MV on an existing table can be done, but any changes to the data that you've made will be lost the first time you refresh. The presumption is that the table will be empty and that you will perform a complete refresh of the MV.

Comment: Yes, we know that the updated data would be lost when we refresh. That's why we need to disable the scheduler job to refresh the data. By "safely", I meant that the reverted MV is back to before without lost of behaviours/properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining  synonym, patch table and views might be a good solution for temporary situation as suggested.
And then..
You can safely recreate materialized view with

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW testmv ON PREBUILT TABLE ...
```

Indexes can be used till refresh. You don't need to re-grant user privileges
Synonyms that crated previously for MV still works after creating MV from prebuilt table.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason to update some data inside the mview? Maybe you need a table, not a mview. Just refresh the materialized view to update the data, or change the related SQL to reflect the dataset you want. Other way it would be as inconsistent state.

Comment: We want to update the data manually because for the purpose of maintenance, some of the refreshed data is not what we want to update to.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Turn the table back to MV

If you understand that after that step, the MV is refreshed with the life data and your changes to the underlaying table are lost, it's OK.

Another way to do the job is to access the MV through a VIEW, and changes the definition of the VIEW for the maintenance work (conceptually "select from MV where not exists (select FROM PATCH) UNION ALL select from PATCH"), and putting it back to "select FROM MV" when done).
(And note that truncate PATCH will have the same effect, and you don't have to change the VIEW...)

Comment: Yes, we are aware of the data switching back after maintenance and that is ok with us...

Comment: The idea of using View.... hmmm... possible but may be cumbersome for us because our existing code reads the MV directly.

Comment: Rename the MV with new name, do the VIEW as explained above using the old name of the MV on the renamed MV  and you will not have to update your client code.